# C++ Kill waiting std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

My secondary thread listens for the channel rabbit and would like it removed from main thread when I call method stopListen() .

```
void PFClient::startListen()
{
this->stop = false;
this-> t = thread(&PFClient::callback,this);    
}

void PFClient::callback()
{
PFAPIResponse* response;
char * temp;
    while (!this->stop)
    {
        try
        {

            std::string receiver_data = "";
            //std::wcout << L"[Callback] oczekiwanie na wiadomość !" << endl;
            receiver_data = this->channel->BasicConsumeMessage()->Message()->Body();
            temp = &receiver_data[0];
... some operation with received data

void PFClient::stopListen()
{
this->stop = true;
}
```

The semaphore is not working properly because it will work only after the next received message.
I try detach(),terminate() but is not working.
How can I brutal kill this process ?

Comment: You really should avoid killing it (resource leaks etc.)

Comment: Can you use a *no-blocking* receive function? Every decent library should have a *block_for* function

Comment: @deviantfan I know , but if I want how Can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

As I've already suggest in my comment, you may use a no-blocking function.

If the library you're using does not provide it, then [`async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) could be a valid alternative:

```
while (this->stop == false) {
  auto receiver_data = std::async(/* ... address function and object*/);

  // wait for the message or until the main thread force the stop
  while (this->stop == false &&
         (receiver_data.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000) == std::future_status::timeout))
    ;

  if (this->stop == false && receiver_data.vaild() == true) {
    // handle the message
  }
}
```

Comment: thx , I will try this !! This is https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient and it's synchronize method